# C++ incomplete type and conversion error

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to write a c++ function using pthreads to do a sort. Receiving the following 2 errors and not sure why:

```
struct threadData{
int thread_id;
int stopIndex;
int startIndex;
};

void createThreads(int k){
struct thread_data threadData;

int numThreads = k;
int i = 0;
int err = 0;
pthread_t *threads = static_cast<pthread_t*>(malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * numThreads));
for(i = 0;i<numThreads;i++){
    threadData[i].thread_id = i;
    //start and stop are 1 indexed
    if(i==0){
        threadData[i].start = ((N/k)*i)+1;
    }
    else{
        threadData[i].start = ((N/k)*i);
    }
    threadData[i].stop = ((N/k)* (i+1));

    err = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, bubbleSort, (void *)&threadData[i]); // replace foo with bubbleSort()
    if(err != 0){
        printf("error creating thread\n");
    }
}
}

void *bubbleSort(void *threadArg){
struct threadData *threadData;
threadData = (struct thread_data *) threadArg;
printf("debug\n");
bool sorted = 0;
int x;
while(!sorted){
    int start = threadData->startIndex; 
    int stop = threadData->stopIndex;

    sorted = 1;
    for(x = num_array[start]; x < num_array[stop-1]; x++){
        if(num_array[x] > num_array[x+1]){
            int temp = num_array[x+1];
            num_array[x+1] = num_array[x];
            num_array[x] = temp;
            sorted = 0;
        }
    }
    if(sorted){
        break;
    }
    sorted = 1;
    for(x = stop; x > start+1; x--){
        if(num_array[x-1] > num_array[x]){
            int temp = num_array[x-1];
            num_array[x-1] = num_array[x];
            num_array[x] = temp;
            sorted = 0;
        }
    }
}
}
```

The errors I am receiving are:
cse451.cpp: In function ‘void createThreads(int)’:
cse451.cpp:99:21: error: aggregate ‘createThreads(int)::thread_data threadData’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
cse451.cpp: In function ‘void* bubbleSort(void*)’:
cse451.cpp:127:38: error: cannot convert ‘bubbleSort(void*)::thread_data*’ to ‘threadData*’ in assignment

I need threadData to contains a startIndex and stopIndex that refers to the bounds of the array that each thread should sort. It appears as though my struct implementation may not be correct but I'm not sure why not. All help is appreciated.

Comment: What is thread_data, where it is defined ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `struct threadData`, but then tried to use the type `struct thread_data` to declare a *variable* named `threadData`.

Comment: that took care of one error. still receiving cse451.cpp:99:21: error: aggregate ‘createThreads(int)::thread_data threadData’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined

Comment: That error suggests you did not fix every occurrence of the problem, but not seeing what changes you made, I could not say for certain.

Comment: yes found the other occurence of the error. thankk you

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the semicolon(;) after startIndex in the structure.

```
struct threadData{
int thread_id;
int stopIndex;
int startIndex
};
```

Comment: does not take care of error: cse451.cpp:99:21: error: aggregate ‘createThreads(int)::thread_data threadData’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined

Comment: Please change struct thread_data threadData; to struct threadData dataxyz;